# Make all tab bar buttons unfocused on specific screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a react native app which uses react navigation (V6.x for sure). My app has a main navigator which is a `bottom-tabs` navigator and contains three screens (tabs). Every one of these screens are stack navigators themselves. Let's say one of my tabs is named `Wallet` (others are `Settings` and `Transactions`). Inside this Wallet screen (which is a stack navigator), i have a `HomePage` screen, a `Receive` screen and a `Send` screen. I want to achieve the following behavior (like below screenshot from designs):
[image]

Whenever the user goes to one of `Send` or `Receive` screens, i want all the tab bar buttons become unfocused (tab bar is still visibe though). And whenever the user gets back to `HomePage` screen (or going to `Settings` or `Transactions` tab by pressing the corresponding tab button), I want the  relevant tab button to get focused again. How can i achieve that with react navigation itself?
(My project is managed by redux, but i prefer not to use state management tools and use react navigation itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but checking child navigation state inside your TabNavigator's `screenOptions`.

```
screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => {
  // get wallet stack route
  const walletStack = navigation.getState().routes.find((route) => route.name === 'Wallet');
  // get current wallet stack focused screen
  const walletRouteName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(walletStack);
  const shouldBeUnfocused =
        walletRouteName === 'Send' || walletRouteName === 'Receive';
  {...}
}
```

Based on `shouldBeUnfocused` you can render proper icons and colors. Here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pafry/unfocus-tab-icons) with example code. You can red [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#customizing-the-appearance) about customizing tab bar's appearance.